# Many to many relationship with order by field creation in symfony3 doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, symfony-forms

Not able to add the extra field while creating the many to many relationship in using doctrine annotation.

```
      /** 
        * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application", inversedBy ="users")
        * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_app",
          * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
          * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="application_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
        *)
private $applications;
```

Using this annotation creating the user_app table contains user_id,application_id with relation ship of user and application table.

I want to add a new column to maintain the order of the application id using the annotation.

```
user_app
----------------
user_id  application_id order_id
 1           2             1
 1           3             2
 2           2             1    
 2           5             2
```

Comment: I believe that the solution to your problem will be in the SELECT statement in the controller or wherever you'll be executing the doctrine query.
So i propose that you create a method in the Entities repository which will retrieve what you want and how you want to order it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can't do this in "Annotation @ORM", try create new entity and set all data's in she.

All Association Mapping - you can see in official documentatio [Doctrine ORM](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)

Comment: Created the third entity class for mapping after that getting the undefined index user error.

Comment: Added new entity but getting undefined index user error.